# "Sent on behalf" not appearing when delegates sending mails

Tags: email, permissions, exchange, outlook

Ringo is a delegate of Paul's mailbox in Exchange, but when Ringo sends mail from Paul's mailbox, the recipient sees "Paul" in the sender field, rather than "Paul Sent On Behalf Of Ringo"

Paul has set "Editor" permissions for Ringo to his mailbox, and Ringo has been granted "Send on behalf of" permissions in Exchange.

Ringo **did** at one time have "Send As" permissions for Paul's mailbox in Exchange, but this has since been removed.

This is also the case for all other delegates to Paul's mailbox.

How do I make it so that emails sent by Paul's delegates show the "Sent On Behalf Of" information in the Sender field?

Using Exchange Server 2007 and Microsoft Office Outlook 2007

Comment: Having performed further tests, it now seems that the "Send As" permissions have for some reason not cleared from when they were originally granted to the delegates of Paul's mailbox.

I created a test ID/mailbox and granted "Send on behalf of" permissions in Exchange, and the mails sent by the test ID do carry the "Sent On Behalf Of" information in the Sender field. 

So despite the fact that I removed "Send As" permissions from the delegates in Exchange, they apparently still have it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that the Sent on behalf of isn't being sent properly?  Sometimes mail clients improperly display the from address, even though there is a sender header.  Double check the message source and make sure that the header is indeed missing.  Just know that not all mail clients will display the "sent on behalf of" message.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me: contact Microsoft if urgent, or try their usenet groups?

Answer (score 0):

Does Ringo actually have Paul's mailbox open as an additional mailbox? Or is Ringo starting a new message, and using the From: field to change to Paul's name?  I believe if Ringo has the mailbox  open as an additional mailbox, it actually sends it as Paul, not on behalf of Paul.

Comment: That is the way he has been doing it, although I have just tested creating a new mail from Ringo's mailbox and selecting Paul's name in the From field, and the result is the same.